# Bad request | discord api v8

Tags: python, api, discord

Code:

```
headers = {"authorization": f"{config['token']}","Content-Type":"application/json"}
data1 = {"recipients":[f"{member.id}"]}
r1 = requests.request("POST", f"https://discord.com/api/v8/users/{ctx.author.id}/channels", headers=headers, data=data1)
```

I get bad request error, code: 0

Every of these values exist like member.id. There is no NoneType

Answer (score 0):

The actual authorization header is of the following format:

```
Authorization: Bot TOKEN
```

So you need to change your header to

```py
headers = {"Authorization": f"Bot {config['token']}", ...}
```